# C# use field 1 value if field 2 empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am running through a set of records using a for each loop, and also doing simple checks to ensure that good data is inserted into a database table.

Sometimes the dataset can be missing the LegistarID value, the change I need to do in my code, is to add a check for LegistarItem,

if the value of LegistarID is missing, but the AgendaItem value is not, then assign the value of AgendaItem to LegistarID

if LegistarId is missing, and there is also no AgendaItem value, then return a message to the user, to let them know that these values need to be present in the dataset they are trying to import.

I know it does not sound complex, but I am having a hard time making this change successfully. I need a bit of help if possible, please.

Here is my code as I currently have it:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    using (Etities db = new Entities())
    {
        foreach (var i in meeting)
        {
            if (i.MeetingID == 0)
            {
                message = string.Format("This file is missing the Meeting ID value of at least 1 record. \n Verify that the data you are trying to upload meets the criteria, and then try to upload your file again.", i.MeetingID);
                return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status, message = message } };
            }
            else
            {
                // development
                var compositeKey = db.MeetingAgenda.Find(i.MeetingID, i.AgendaItem);                               
                if (compositeKey == null)
                {
                    // Add new
                    // development
                    db.MeetingAgenda.Add(i);
                    //
                }
                else
                {
                    // Serves as an update, or addition of a previously imported dataset
                    db.Entry(compositeKey).CurrentValues.SetValues(i.MeetingID);
                    db.Entry(compositeKey).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        status = true;
    }
}
else
{
    message = string.Format("Please, verify that the file you are trying to upload is correctly formatted, and that the data it contains, meets the expected criteria, then click the upload button again. \n Thank you!");
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status, message = message } };
}
```

I think that part of the code I need is something like this:

```
else if (i.LegistarID == 0 and i.AgendaItem != 0)
{
    i.LegistarID = i.AgendaItem                             
}
```

I just am unsure how in the current code place it.

Comment: Is this a POST action that was invoked by a view? In that case you could add errors to ModelState and return the same view with the posted data. How do you interact with the user on successs?

Comment: I return a message via JavaScript to let them know the rows have been inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check all rows before returning a result.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    var errors = new List<string> ();
    var rowCounter = 1;
    using (Etities db = new Entities ()) {
        foreach (var i in meeting) {
            if (i.MeetingID == 0) {
                // Let the user know this row is bad 
                errors.Add ($"Row {rowCounter}: This file is missing the Meeting ID. Verify that the data you are trying to upload meets the criteria, and then try to upload your file again.");
            }
            // Check if LegistarID is missing
            if (i.LegistarID == 0) {
                // Check if Agenda Item is present
                if (i.AgendaItem == 0) {
                    errors.Add ($"Row {rowCounter}: Meeting has no LegistarID and no Agenda Item. Please check data");                    
                } else {
                    i.LegistarID = i.AgendaItem
                }
            }

            // development
            var compositeKey = db.MeetingAgenda.Find (i.MeetingID, i.AgendaItem);
            if (compositeKey == null) {
                // Add new
                // development
                db.MeetingAgenda.Add (i);
                //
            } else {
                // Serves as an update, or addition of a previously imported dataset
                db.Entry (compositeKey).CurrentValues.SetValues (i.MeetingID);
                db.Entry (compositeKey).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            rowCounter++;
        }
        // If there are errors do not save and return error message
        if (errors.Count > 0) {            
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = false, message = string.Join ("\n", errors) } };
        }
        db.SaveChanges ();
        status = true;
    }
} else {
    message = string.Format ("Please, verify that the file you are trying to upload is correctly formatted, and that the data it contains, meets the expected criteria, then click the upload button again. \n Thank you!");
    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status, message = message } };
}
```

Comment: Hello Steven, I like your solution. When I try to implement it I get an error on this part: errors.Add - the suggestion for potential fix, is to replace it with AddRange, but since I am unfamiliar and have not done research on this, I have not changed it. Do you know why this error might be happening? Thank you.

Comment: Oh I think is because "Add" method does not take 2 arguments. But I see in your suggestion you want to pass the rowCounter. Should I just remove the rowCounter, or is there another method I can use that accomplish the same task of adding to the list, but also accepts more than 1 argument? Thanks

Comment: Hi @erasmocarlos, sorry I took your string.Format line and tried to convert it to errors.Add(). Somehow I made sort of a copy & paste error and it seems I forgot to move the parameter of the string.Format to the interpolated string. You can either use the interpolated string version or use your original string.Format inside the errors.Add() statement.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this.

Comment: the question didn't ask to return a list of errors, but anyway...I learned something: next time I'll answer to a specific question like this one I'll add some random features, just in case the user needs them. If he doesn't....well, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

The "if(i.MeetingID == 0)" else is redundant, because you are returning if the condition is met. So to avoid unneeded/confusing nesting I would rewrite the actual code (of the loop only) as:

```
 foreach (var i in meeting)
 {
    if (i.MeetingID == 0)
    {
       message = string.Format("This file is missing the Meeting ID value of at least 1 record. \n Verify that the data you are trying to upload meets the criteria, and then try to upload your file again.", i.MeetingID);
       return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status, message = message } };
    }

    // development
    var compositeKey = db.MeetingAgenda.Find(i.MeetingID, i.AgendaItem);                               
    if (compositeKey == null)
    {
       // Add new
       // development
       db.MeetingAgenda.Add(i);
       //
    }
    else
    {
        // Serves as an update, or addition of a previously imported dataset
        db.Entry(compositeKey).CurrentValues.SetValues(i.MeetingID);
        db.Entry(compositeKey).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }     
 }
```

Then, I would add the new condition in between the MeetingID = 0 check and the rest of the code, like this:

```
     foreach (var i in meeting)
     {
        if (i.MeetingID == 0)
        {
           message = string.Format("This file is missing the Meeting ID value of at least 1 record. \n Verify that the data you are trying to upload meets the criteria, and then try to upload your file again.", i.MeetingID);
           return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status, message = message } };
        }

        // *** New check on LegistarID and AgendaItem ***
        if(i.LegistarID == 0)
        {
           // Is there a chance to fill LegistarID with AgendaItem?
           if(i.AgendaItem != 0)
           {
               // Yes, fill it and then let the rest of the code flow peacefully.
               i.LegistarID = i.AgendaItem
           }
           else
           {
               // No way: I must stop the procedure here and warn the user about this.
               // return "these values need to be present in the dataset they are trying to import."
           }
        }

        // development
        var compositeKey = db.MeetingAgenda.Find(i.MeetingID, i.AgendaItem);                               
        if (compositeKey == null)
        {
           // Add new
           // development
           db.MeetingAgenda.Add(i);
           //
        }
        else
        {
            // Serves as an update, or addition of a previously imported dataset
            db.Entry(compositeKey).CurrentValues.SetValues(i.MeetingID);
            db.Entry(compositeKey).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }     
     }
```